# List Manipulation wrong output

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

I wrote this block:

```
stst = "Hello World!@#"

empt = []

def shplit(stst):
    tst = stst.split()
    print tst
    for i in tst:
        empt = list(i)
    print empt


shplit(stst)
```

what I get from the prints is:

```
['Hello', 'World!@#']
['W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', '@', '#']
```

I can't figure out why the word 'Hello' doesn't appear at all in the second list. 
Why is this happening??

Comment: In your own words, why *should* it appear? Go through it step by step, and explain what you expect to happen to `empt` at every step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is incorrect:

```
for i in tst:
    empt = list(i)
print empt # this happens after the loop
```

When you `print empt`, the loop has finished, so you only see the value from the last iteration of the loop. If you want to see all iterations, indent the `print` one level:

```
for i in tst:
    empt = list(i)
    print empt # this happens inside the loop
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to fill `empt` with all of the various `i`s, use `list.extend`:

```
for i in tst:
    empt.extend(i)
print empt
```

This gives:

```
>>> shplit(stst)
['Hello', 'World!@#']
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', '@', '#']
```

Comment: Hi, The last block you wrote is what I was looking for. Can you explain about the difference between the list and extend functions? thanks\

Comment: Why not read the docs - [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). All your code did was overwrite `empt` with a new list each time.